# The UBUNTU Graphics Catch 22

Tags: grub2, monitor, livedvd, signal

Trying to use a Live DVD to run Ubuntu 14.04.1, I get the "Monitor signal out of range" error.
I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up the command line.
I do `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and remove # from GRUB_GFXMODE and change it to 1280x1024 and overwrite the file.
I then `sudo update-grub` and get:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow.
```

I find that I could start in safe graphics mode, but that isn't available on Live DVD. 
I try to install it normally, but I can't see anything beyond the install screen when to move along the installation.

Comment: I didn't exactly understand how did you want to update grub on LiveDVD which is readonly medium.